# Unable to install Dynamics CRM2011 on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, installation, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I'm attempting to install Dynamics CRM 2011 on an AWS EC2 instance (Server 2008 R2 64 bit)
When I run Microsoft.Crm.Server.Setup.exe from the Server\amd64 folder on the installation CD I get a message telling me the .exe is not a valid Win32 application.  I've installed this on other x64 R2 servers with out problems.

Any thoughts gratefully received, I'm a bit stumped...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, some sort of corruption on the media. Downloaded again from MSDN and working without problems now.